# Function to find duplicate values after applying a function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like a function in C++ which finds an item in a collection which has the same value of `function(key)` as another item in the collection.

e.g.

```
std::set<int> ints = {1, -1, 3};
// Finds an item in the set with the same absolute value as
// another item.
int* dupe = find_duplicates(ints, [](int x) { return std::abs(x); });
// Should print -1 or 1
if (dupe != 0) std::cout << "Found dupe: " << *dupe << std::endl;
```

However, I'm having trouble even writing the function signature for this method.

In Java it'd be something like `static Integer findDuplicates<T, U>(Iterable<T>, Function<T, U> func)`.

In C++ I've got as far as the following, but it doesn't compile:

```
template<template <typename T> Collection, typename U>
T* find_duplicates(
    const Collection<T>& collection,
    const std::function<U(T)>& func) { ... }
```

The error I get is `error: 'T' does not name a type`.

Any pointers? (I'd also be interested in a way to get around the use of the "raw" pointer to `T*`, but that's probably better for a separate question)

Comment: I think you missed one `typename` before `Collection` too

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [std::find_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) no?

Comment: Why not follow the `STL` convention of passing generic *iterators* rather than a container to your algorithm?

Comment: @Galik Not OP, but iterators are not fun to work with.   They are always cumbersome and the details behind them are opaque unless you have very advanced understanding of them.

Comment: By the way - are you sure that the `func` should return some `U`? Shouldn't that be a predicate that will take `T` and always return `bool`?

Comment: @xaxxon Iterators pay off in the long run. If you want to apply subsequent algorithms to a selected range within the original container, you don't have to create a new container to pass to the next algorithm, you just pass the new iterators.

Comment: @Galik C++ is very much a "if it's technically sufficient then it's done" kind of language.. and that oftentimes makes it not as fun to use.   Anyhow, ranges are looking good.   Maybe one day MSVC will be able to compile them.

Comment: @xaxxon Or look at `gsl::span` which combines two iterators in a container like object (proposed for standardization). https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/docs/gsl-intro.md#gslspan-what-is-gslspan-and-what-is-it-for

Comment: @Galik I won't touch GSL.  The issue history on it is full of mindblowingly stupid implementation issues that have been sitting around for a year+.  They also change the API without warning or versioning and are difficult to get patches through to.  Immensely frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `T` is unrecognizable and virtually useless. You should introduce the type `T` earlier and **then** use it to specify the `Collection`, like so:

```
template<typename T, template <typename> typename Collection, typename U>
T* find_duplicates(const Collection<T>& collection,
                   const std::function<U(T)>& func)
{
    // some logic here
}
```

Also: notice that you missed a single `typename` before the `Collection`, as I pointed out in a comment previously. The above example is adjusted for that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, something like this should work,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    std::set<int> ints = {1, -1, 3};

    auto dupe = std::find_if(ints.begin(),ints.end(),[&](const int& first){
            return std::find_if(ints.begin(),ints.end(),[&](const int& second) {
                // so a the same value isn't checked against itself..
                if (&first == &second) return false;
                return std::abs(first) == std::abs(second);
            }) != ints.end();
         } );

    if (dupe != ints.end()) std::cout << "Found dupe: " << *dupe << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/70mqn0)

Answer (score 0):

Don't be so picky about your function parameter types.  You don't really need `collection` to be a class template specialization, just something you can iterate over (which could even be a C-style array).  `func` just needs to be invokable, and forcing it to be a `std::function` object can be less efficient than directly using a function pointer or lambda, because of the type erasure `std::function` adds and then resolves.

So a working declaration could be

```
template <typename Collection, typename Func>
auto find_duplicates(Collection& collection, const Func& func)
  -> typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(collection))>::value_type*;
```

I would do:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

// Calling with an rvalue collection would be bad news.
template <typename Collection, typename Func>
void find_duplicates(Collection&&, const Func&) = delete;

template <typename Collection, typename Func>
auto find_duplicates(Collection& collection, const Func& func)
   -> typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(collection))>::value_type*
{
    auto iter = std::begin(collection);
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(iter)>::value_type;
    auto ptr_compare = [&func](value_type* p, value_type* q)
    { return func(*p) < func(*q); };
    std::set<value_type*, decltype(ptr_compare)> iter_set{ptr_compare};
    for (; iter != std::end(collection); ++iter) {
        auto insert_result = iter_set.insert(std::addressof(*iter));
        if (!insert_result.second)
            return *insert_result.first;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Sometimes a raw pointer really is the answer. It implies the value might be null, and that the pointer has no ownership relation to the object. In this case, not using the pointer after it's invalidated by modifying or destroying the container is up to the caller, but it has the usual pointer-to-container-element invalidation semantics which depend on the container details.

This won't work with `std::vector<bool>` or any other pseudo-container where `*collection.begin()` has a "proxy" type.  If you want to support those and can use C++17 [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) or `boost::optional`, you could return an `optional<value_type>` instead of a raw pointer, though this will make a copy of the returned duplicated value.  If you can't use those or a copy is undesirable, maybe write a template class `iter_or_null<InputIter>` that contains an iterator, has `operator*` and `operator->` that just call the iterator's operators, and satisfies the [`NullablePointer` concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/NullablePointer).

Answer (score 0):

You're actually being too restrictive with your template. You want your template to take any container for which std::begin and std::end are defined, and any function object that can accept an instance of whatever the container contains. In the template world, you just accept any type, use it the way you would like to, and if the caller doesn't provide a compatibly-typed object, they will get a compilation error.

Further, there's no need to use std::function - it will end up potentially allocating memory when you can just accept the function object as a parameter with a deduced type.

With C++14, auto-deduced return types and auto parameters to lambdas allow you to write very generic code. Here's my solution. It returns an iterator into the container pointing to the first duplicate found, or std::end(c) if no duplicate is found.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

template<typename C, typename F>
auto find_duplicates(const C & c, const F & func)
{
     return std::find_if(std::begin(c), std::end(c), [&](const auto & first) {
         return std::any_of(std::begin(c), std::end(c), [&](const auto & second) {
             return &first != &second && func(first) == func(second);
         });
     });

}

int main()
{
    std::set<int> s{1, 3, -1};

    auto const iter = find_duplicates(s, [](int x) { return std::abs(x); });

    if (iter != std::end(s))
    {
        std::cout << "Duplicate found: " << *iter << '\n';
    }
}
```

EDIT: I just noticed you specified the C++11 tag. It's only a little more complicated in C++11:

```
template<typename C, typename F>
auto find_duplicates(const C & c, const F & func) -> decltype(std::begin(c))
{
     using ContainedType = decltype(*std::begin(c));
     return std::find_if(std::begin(c), std::end(c), [&](const ContainedType & first) {
         return std::any_of(std::begin(c), std::end(c), [&](const ContainedType & second) {
             return &first != &second && func(first) == func(second);
         });
     });
}
```